# ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to run python script to read csv file and index in Elasticsearch.

- Python version : 3.10.4
- elastic version: 7.9.0

My code is as below:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
from collections.abc import Mapping,MutableMapping
import csv

# Create the elasticsearch client.
es = Elasticsearch(host = "localhost", port = 9200)

# Open csv file and bulk upload
with open('sampleInput.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    helpers.bulk(es, reader, index='sampleIndex1')
```

Getting the error on running script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\C88455\VsCode\ESDemo3.py", line 1, in <module>
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
  File "C:\Users\C88455\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .client import Elasticsearch
  File "C:\Users\C88455\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..transport import Transport
  File "C:\Users\C88455\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\transport.py", line 4, in <module>   
    from .connection import Urllib3HttpConnection
  File "C:\Users\C88455\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .http_urllib3 import Urllib3HttpConnection
  File "C:\Users\C88455\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 3, 
in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\C88455\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\C88455\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 29, in <module>   
    from .connection import (
  File "C:\Users\C88455\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "C:\Users\C88455\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>     
    from .connection import is_connection_dropped
  File "C:\Users\C88455\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 3, in <module>   
    from .wait import wait_for_read
  File "C:\Users\C88455\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\wait.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .selectors import (
  File "C:\Users\C88455\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\selectors.py", line 14, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple, Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\C88455\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

I already tried using `from collections.abc import Mapping` but still does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Update the elastic client library to 7.10 at least as it changed the deprecated use of collections.Mapping that gives you this error

Comment: Hi @orhtej2 Tried with elastic client library to 7.10, still the same issue.

Comment: Resolved by downgrading the python version to 3.9.8. Thanks.

Comment: That import change is explicitly mentioned in [7.10.1 release notes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/master/release-notes.html#rn-7-10-1), not sure why it didn't help